# If $x,y∈(-π,π]$, then find the area of the polygon formed by points $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $\lfloor|\sin x|\rfloor+\lfloor|\cos y|\rfloor=2$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, graphing-functions, area

> If $x,y∈(-π,π]$, then find the area of the polygon formed by points $(x,y)$ satisfying the equation $\lfloor|\sin x|\rfloor+\lfloor|\cos y|\rfloor=2$.

My attempts include using a graphing tool and taking $\sin x= \pm1$ and $\cos y=\pm1$ for $x=\pm \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ and $y=0,\pi$.
How do you solve this further?
$\lfloor\,\cdot\,\rfloor$ represents the greatest integer function / floor function.

Comment: Let $X=|\sin(x)|$ and $Y=|\cos(y)|$. Using that $-1\le\sin(x)\le 1$ and $-1\le\cos(y)\le 1$, what are the possible values for $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You know that the equation is satisfied for $x \in \{-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\}$ and $y \in \{0, \pi\}$. So if you take the cartesian product of those two sets you have the list of all the points satisfying this equation : $\{(-\frac{\pi}{2}, 0),\; (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi),\;(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0),\; (\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi)\}$. You can see by graphing, or simply by looking at the coordinates that this forms a square of side $\pi$. So the area you are looking for is $\pi^2$.